# round in Smarty shows wrong result

Tags: smarty, rounding

In my Smarty 3 template I have this code:

```
{$a=8.34}
{$b=8.33}
{$a-$b|round:2}
```

Expected result is: **0.01**

But I receive this: **0.0099999999999998**

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`Smarty2` applied the modifier to the result of the complete expression.

`Smarty3` does it just on the **direct prepending value**.

So in `Smarty3` you have to use brackets:

```
{($a-$b)|round:2}
```

That should solve it.